# Too much connections to db using DataReader

Tags: c#, odbc, datareader, timesten

Every time i get a value from a response from a odbcconnection by datareader, i made a connection to the database (if i have a query that return 9 fields, i have 9 connection to db), and i want to do only 1 connection and retrieve all information. it's possible with datareader ? I need to use other method of connection ?

Best Regards.

Code:

```
    string strSql = "SELECT G.COMPANY_ID, U.USER_ID, U.GROUP_ID, U.NAME, U.DISPLAY_NAME, U.EMAIL, U.IS_CORPORATE, U.CALL_PARK, U.CALL_PICKUP, U.PCHUNTING, U.OUT_OF_OFFICE, U.DND, U.HOTLINE, U.PIN, U.FORCE_PIN_CHECKED, U.PCHUNTING_TYPE, U.DND_END_TIMESTAMP, U.DND_CONTACT, U.OUT_OF_OFFICE_TYPE, U.LANGUAGE, U.AVAILABLE_TIMESTAMP, U.LAST_DIALLED_NUMBER, U.LAST_INCOMING_CALL, U.LAST_MISSED_CALL, U.CALL_PICKUP_GROUP_ID, U.HOTLINE_NUMBER, U.PORTAL_PASSWORD, U.PROFILE, U.MAIN_NUMBER, U.DUAL_OUTGOING_CTRANSFER, U.MY_CALL_PICKUP, U.VM_RECONNECT_NOTIFY, U.SPARE_STRING1, U.INSERT_DATE, U.INSERT_USER, U.UPDATE_DATE, U.UPDATE_USER " +
                            "FROM {0}_TT_USER U LEFT OUTER JOIN {0}_TT_GROUP G ON  U.GROUP_ID = G.GROUP_ID " +
                            "WHERE USER_ID = :USER_ID ";

            conn = new OdbcConnection(GetIpCntrxTimestenConnString(opCode));
            cmd = new OdbcCommand(
                 string.Format(strSql
                             , config.GetIpCntrxEsmViewName(opCode))
                 , conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":USER_ID", user_id);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conn.Open();

            dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            object[] meta = new object[dataReader.FieldCount];

            int NumberOfColums = dataReader.GetValues(meta);
```

Comment: show some code please!! In general number of connections should be kept the lowest possible...

Comment: could you paste your code please? we need to see it to answer

Answer (score 1):

No, you need another way to query.

Instead of one query per field, `SELECT` all 9 at once and close the connection right away.

Another problem with this approach is that there's no layering whatsoever.  I wouldn't like mingling UI and database code together.  There's no abstraction your way.

Comment: I dont have UI code right here... Where did u see that ? The problem is that, that method getvalues, every time it get a value, made a connection to the database...

Comment: when you said "field", I thought "textfield".  My mistake.

Comment: And i do a query that returns 9 fields.. but to get each one it connect to database.. that's my problem..

Comment: Should be one connection, one query, close the connection.  If your solution is making a connection for each field, you'd be better off finding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a StringBuilder and AppendLine your select queries. Loop through your dbReader and store in an List thats the best i can come up with. I do understand you want one call with 9 different queries but either way there is going to be overhead on your sql machine or program machine.